# How to set a DEBUG for appsink plugin in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Does anyone have a clue on how to set gst-debug for a appsrc plugin in my pipeline via **a pipeline application (c file )**?

(Just like how we insert --gst-debug=appsrc:9 in gst-launch-1.0 command line on terminal?)

Thanks !

Comment: What command are you using for logging in your appsrc? GST_DEBUG_OBJECT and company, or GST_DEBUG and company?

Comment: GST_DEBUG and company

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using GST_DEBUG, GST_INFO, etc. those get filtered by the general debug level in GST_DEBUG, e.g.

`export GST_DEBUG=2`

...will only log calls to GST_ERROR and higher.

Then you can mix and match that with the element level debugging:

`export GST_DEBUG=2,videoconvert:5,avdec_h264:4`

This would make the general debug level ERROR, videoconvert DEBUG level, and avdec_h264 INFO level.

If you use GST_DEBUG=appsrc:5, you could also use GST_DEBUG_OBJECT and company and do your appsrc logging like this:

`GST_DEBUG_OBJECT(appsrc, "SOME LOGGING");`

This would apply to any appsrc elements in your system, though usually there is just one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstInfo.html#gst-debug-set-threshold-from-string or similar functions to set debug level from the application.

Or you can simply set the environment variable GST_DEBUG when running your application:

```
GST_DEBUG=appsrc:9 ./yourapplication
```